# How can I change background images and text on navigation menu link when it’s selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change background images and text on navigation menu link when it’s selected

When the user clicks on one of the navigation links, the text will change color and background image will changed too. The user should stay on the same page.

It’s working in static files on my machine, but it doesn’t work when I post it online.

Comment: Do you want to know how it works? Or is it not working and you want to fix something?

Comment: “The tricky part is all these were all in only one HTML file” — that’s actually not tricky at all. CSS and JavaScript can be included directly in HTML pages via the `<script>` and `<style>` tags.

Comment: ya.. sorry about that.. if you have a better way to work it out .. then is good..

Comment: the code that i am using is working on static.. but when i post it online, it didn't work

Comment: paul : yup.. i did that.. i just separate it cz i think is more clearer..

Comment: hmm.. what i mean in 1 html file is although there are other pages in separate link, but there are just 1 html. 

example: all | iphone | android| windows|

Comment: @ice: sure, it’s just that that’s not really relevant to your question. Saying that that’s the tricky part suggests it’s something you don’t understand.

Comment: haha.. :p ya.. i really did not understand.. i am a designer actually.. a very very newbie to css and html.. sorry if i sound silly :P

Comment: @ice: ah, I think I’ve got you. I’ve amended the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you'll find anybody to write the code for you. Why not start and ask again if you get stuck

Comment: @ paul : Thank you :) i edit out all the extra#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what You need:

http://jsfiddle.net/nVz43/1/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) — Write less, do more.

```
// bind a click event to all the links
$('#o_nav').find('a').click(function() {
  // make sure other backgrounds are removed
  $('#o_nav').find('a').removeClass('aSelected');
  // add selected background to clicked link
  $(this).addClass('aSelected');
});
```